# Is there any action /filter hook I can use to disable login for some user role?

Tags: users, login

I want to block user role called "pending" loging to the site. (pending is a custom user rolled created by me).

Is there any action/filter to block all users who are in "pendin" user role?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn off the ability to login?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208677/how-do-i-turn-off-the-ability-to-login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use [authenticate](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate) hook:

```
add_action( 'authenticate' , 'check_custom_authentication', 20, 3 );                   
function check_custom_authentication ( $user, $username, $password ) {             
    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') && in_array('pending', $user->roles) ) {
        return new WP_Error('pending', 'Your error msg');
    }
}
```