# wp_redirect on base wp-admin and login

Tags: plugin-development, wp-redirect, template-redirect, init

**UPDATE**: I've done some more research on my problem and have narrowed down the problem further. The question below has been very rewritten from the original.

---

I'm trying set up a plugin to redirect ALL page requests - front-end, admin, login, etc - to an additional code validation page (whether that's advisable or not is moot, it's what the client wants). Based on the functions, hooks, and filters I need to use, I've determined that the earliest possible hook I can tie the redirect function to is `wp`:

`add_action('wp', 'cg_check_validation');`

The function goes through some `$_COOKIE` and `$_POST` validation before eventually:

`wp_redirect(add_query_arg('validate-access', 1, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

The following filter and action were set up to handle the redirection:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'cg_redirect_query_vars');

function cg_redirect_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'validate-access';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action('parse_request', 'cg_redirect_parse_request');

function cg_redirect_parse_request(&$wp)
{
    // if our custom access validation query var exists, load our custom plugin view
    // then exit the script
    if (array_key_exists('validate-access', $wp->query_vars)) {
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/validate-access.php');
        exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

The redirect and code validation is working for ALMOST every page, however the login page and the base admin page (`/wp-admin/`) are not being redirected at all. What would be causing these pages to be exempt?

**EDIT**: Another update! The redirect is ONLY working on admin pages that have query strings. So, for example, the redirect works on `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`, but not `/wp-admin/edit-comments.php`. Though having identified the problem, I'm no closer to solving it -- my best guess is that `parse_request` or `query_vars` isn't fired on pages without query strings?

Comment: you should see some sort of error if you have debugging enabled.

Comment: I do - there's no error, the redirect just... doesn't happen.

Comment: `parse_request` only fires on pages with a main query.

Comment: So how can I 100% reliably redirect EVERY page?

Answer (score 0):

Hooking to `admin_init` is what you want, for doing a redirect while inside admin.  So you'd need both - that one, and the hook to `template_redirect` for the front-end handler.

Comment: No such luck; `template_redirect` is correctly working for front-end, `admin_init` is not redirecting on the back-end.

Comment: Actually, I partially retract that: it isn't redirect for the LOGIN page, which it needs to. Once I'm actually ON the back-end, it.... gives me a too many redirects error. I'm sure that's solvable, though.

Comment: Yeah, you are in a redirect loop which you need to solve by examining the page you are on and making sure you really want to redirect it.  Regarding login dialog, see the second answer here:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/disable-or-redirect-wp-login-php - which also gives you a hint about using `$pagenow` in your logical test.