# Logout Redirect and also WP-login.php Redirect

Tags: functions, admin, redirect, login, logout

I am not very advanced in php. I have this function that prevents wp-login.php access with redirection

```
add_action('init','custom_login');

function custom_login(){
global $pagenow;
if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && !is_user_logged_in()) {
wp_redirect('http://yoursite.com/');
exit();
 }
}
```

from here -> [Disable Or Redirect WP-login.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/disable-or-redirect-wp-login-php)

which is actually redirecting and not allowing access to wp-login.php, which is the first thing i want to have, but for logging out just redirects to 'http://yoursite.com/'

What i want to add is:

1.When the user logout from front-end redirect to current page -probably i could do this with

```
get_permalink() 

    or 

$location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
wp_safe_redirect($location);
```

2.When the user logout from back-end redirect to home url.

-I know that i can use is_admin() to determinate the front and back -end areas, but i need a little help to make the magic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with this code (paste it to your functions.php)

```
function auto_redirect_external_after_logout(){
    // check if user is leaving from admin
    // is_admin() check would not work here probably as we left the admin already
    if ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'wp-admin' ) ){
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example-from-admin.com' );
    } else {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example-from-front.com' );
    }
    //make sure to call exit after redirect
    exit;
}

//execute the code above on logout
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_external_after_logout');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Levi, code works fine , i did something like that:

function auto_redirect_external_after_logout(){
    
    if ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'wp-admin' ) ){
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
    } else {
  $location = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        wp_redirect( $location );
    }
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_external_after_logout'); 

I guess first IF statement is to check if user is in the back-end yes?
Is this going to work, if my website is over https? 
Also how can i disable wp-login.php, or redirect?

Comment: Yeah, in the first `if` statement we check what was the last page before the 
 current script started to be executed, `strpos()` is used to check if *wp-admin* was part of this url. It will work with https as well. 

What do you mean by disabling wp-login? How would you log in as an administrator if you redirect that page?

Comment: Well, I already have front-end way to login with a widget, so i would also like to include disabling or not giving access to the wp-login page, as you see in my above code.